# How to convert assembly to pseudo code?

Tags: assembly, x86, c

I have the following assembly. I don't know how to follow assembly. I was wondering if there is a way to convert assembly to a human readable pseudo code or better yet C code:

```
init:
 mov    eax, [ebp+8]    # pointer to key
 push   eax
 mov    eax, [ebp+c]    # pointer to ciphertext
 push   eax
 mov    eax, [ebp+10]   # ciphertext length
 push   eax
 mov    eax, [ebp+1c]   # pointer to plaintext
 push   eax
 xor    ecx, ecx    # loop counter

loop:
 xor    edx, edx
 mov    eax, ecx
 mov    ebx, 0x6
 div    ebx

 mov    eax, [esp+c]
 add    eax, edx
 mov    al, byte ptr [eax]
 sub    al, 0x41

 mov    ebx, [esp+8]
 add    ebx, ecx
 mov    bl, byte ptr [ebx]
 sub    bl, 0x41

 sub    bl, al
 jns    tail
 add    bl, 0x1a

tail:
 add    bl, 0x41
 mov    eax, [esp]
 mov    [eax+ecx], bl

 inc    ecx
 cmp    ecx, [esp+4]
 jl loop
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although rewriting assembly to pseudo C is not technically reverse engineering, I'll try to help

```
init:
 mov    eax, [ebp+8]
 push   eax
 mov    eax, [ebp+0xc]
 push   eax
 mov    eax, [ebp+0x10]
 push   eax
 mov    eax, [ebp+0x1c]
 puse   eax
 xor    ecx, ecx
```

This block just basically sets up parameters, as already mentioned `ecx` is a `counter`.

```
loop:
 xor    edx, edx
 mov    eax, ecx
 mov    ebx, 0x6
 div    ebx
```

Here `edx` is zeroed out, counter is moved to `eax` and unsigned division by 6 is performed. `div` stores the quotient in `eax` and remainder in `edx`.

```
mov    eax, [esp+0xc]
add    eax, edx
mov    al, [eax]
sub    al, 0x41
```

Here pointer from the key is accessed at offset `edx` and 0x41 is subtracted.

```
char a = key[counter % 6] - 0x41;
```

On to the next block

```
mov    ebx, [esp+8]
add    ebx, ecx
mov    bl, [ebx]
sub    bl, 0x41
```

Here pointer from the `ciphertext` is accessed at offset `counter` and 0x41 is subtracted.

```
char b = ciphertext[counter] - 0x41;
```

Next

```
sub    bl, al
jns    tail
add    bl, 0x1a
```

Here `a` and `b` are subtracted and if difference is less than zero 0x1a is added to `b`;

```
b = b - a;
if(b < 0) b += 0x1a;
```

Next:

```
tail:
 add    bl, 0x41
 mov    eax, [esp]
 mov    byte ptr [eax+ecx], bl
 inc    ecx
 cmp    ecx, [esp+4]
 jl loop
```

Here 0x41 is added back to `b` and its written to `plaintext` at offset `counter`.

```
plaintext[counter] = b+0x41;
counter++;
```

This was done in a loop with `length` as the limit.

```
while(counter < length)
```

Equivalent complete code.

```
void decode(char *key, char *ciphertext, size_t length, char *plaintext){
    size_t counter = 0; 
    do{
        char diff = ciphertext[counter] - key[counter % 6];
        plaintext[counter++] = 0x41 + diff + (diff < 0 ? 0x1a : 0);
    }
    while(counter < length);
}
```

Comment: Probably not much sense commenting on a closed question, but the subtraction is the wrong way around—key is supposed to be subtracted from cipher text. Also it's the Vigenere cipher.